# optimized two query as one and separates results

Tags: php, mysql

How can I optimize this code? Is it possible to be one query?
This code provides my advertising message into my web. meanwhile is it correct to put my massages in database and then call them?

```
$result1 = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM msg WHERE type='container'" , $link);

    while($end = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        $msg=$end['msg'];
        $msg_class=$end['msg_class'];

 $msg_container[]='<div class="'.$msg_class.'">'.$msg.'</div>';
    }


$result2 = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM msg WHERE type='leftbar'" , $link);

    while($end = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        $msg=$end['msg'];
        $title=$end['title'];
        $msg_class=$end['msg_class'];

 $msg_leftbar[]='<div class="'.$msg_class.'"><h2>'.$title.'</h2><hr />'.$msg.'</div>';
    }
```

edited:
if on of query has ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 , like that:

```
$result1 = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM msg WHERE type='container' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1" , $link);
```

and other hasn't:

```
$result2 = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM msg WHERE type='leftbar'" , $link);
```

Now can i mix them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it in one sql and decide in the while block which type it is

```
    $result1 = mysql_query( "(SELECT * FROM msg WHERE type='container' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) UNION 
    ( SELECT * FROM msg WHERE type = 'leftbar')" , $link);

                while($end = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) 
            {
            $msg = $end['msg'];
        $title = $end['title'];
        $msg_class = $end['msg_class'];
        $type = $end['type'];

        switch($type)
        {
            case 'container':
                $msg_container[]='<div class="'.$msg_class.'">'.$msg.'</div>';
            break;
            case 'leftbar':
                $msg_leftbar[]='<div class="'.$msg_class.'"><h2>'.$title.'</h2><hr />'.$msg.'</div>';
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I edited my question, Please check back again, tnx pal

Comment: Edited for changed question

Answer (score 4):

yes you can try this

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT msg, title, msg_class, type FROM msg WHERE type in ('container', 'leftbar' )" , $link);

while($end = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

     $msg       =   $end['msg'];
     $msg_class =   $end['msg_class'];
     $title     =   $end['title'];

    if ($end['type'] == 'container') {
        $msg_container[]='<div class="'.$msg_class.'">'.$msg.'</div>';
    }

    if ($end['type'] == 'leftbar') {
        $msg_leftbar[]='<div class="'.$msg_class.'"><h2>'.$title.'</h2><hr />'.$msg.'</div>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of having 2 separated conditions, consider merging them into one `if-else` statement for better performance. `type` can be one of two options according to the question.

Comment: You could also look at changing `('container', 'leftbar')` into an array to make it expandable.

Comment: I edited my question, Please check back again, tnx pal

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can use one query and one loop and have a condition inside that loop that checks which type is the current row belongs to.

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM msg WHERE type='container' OR type='leftbar'" , $link);

    while($end = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $msg=$end['msg'];
       $msg_class=$end['msg_class'];
       $title = $end['title'];

       if($end['type'] == "container"){
          $msg_container[]='<div class="'.$msg_class.'">'.$msg.'</div>';
       } else {
          $msg_leftbar[]='<div class="'.$msg_class.'"><h2>'.$title.'</h2><hr />'.$msg.'</div>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: I edited my question, Please check back again, tnx pal